# How to find the path to appdata folder for the logged in user in windows service

Tags: c#, appdata

I wrote a service and in the code I tried to get the `AppData` folder's path:

```
C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\
```

I tried:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

But I got:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the AppData folder of the **Account** running the service. (**System Account**)
There is no other user involved in it.

If you want a particular user's **AppData** folder, run the Windows Service under that user's account.

Comment: I searched online and found to run the windows services under a user account, I need to specify the username and the password. I would like to know how I can get the username and password of the currently log in user?

Comment: You cannot get it from code. You need to be the current user and know it. Once you know you can set it in windows service properties or from code.